# Magento 2 : How to make lastname and email as optional for customers?

Tags: magento-2.1, validation, customer-attribute

I wanted to make last name and email of customer as optional in admin. 
Here is my code

**ui_component/customer_form.xml**

```
 <field name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

<field name="lastname">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="validate-alphanum-with-spaces" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

And I have changed the attributes "is_require" value 1 to 0 in db table(eav_attribute) , Still i am getting server side validation.

Please check the screenshot

[image]

Please help me to resolve this. thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing this issue anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Override this file
`Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository`

Comment: Thank you very much @mahalakshmi , works like a charm...

Comment: Can you please share the whole code.. i need this

Comment: @user53836 please share the whole code